# CAML Query Helper to retrieve Announcements List

Tags: caml-query

Consider this as my code to retrieve an Announcements List from SharePoint 2010 site:

```
<Query>
<Where>
  <Or>
     <Or>
     <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Title"></FieldRef>
      <Value Type="Text"></Value>
     </Eq>
     <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Dream_x0020_Destination" />
      <Value Type="Text"></Value>
     </Eq>
    </Or>      
      <IsNotNull>
      <FieldRef Name="PPP"  Ascending="False"></FieldRef>
      <Value Type="Currency"></Value>
      </IsNotNull> 
    </Or>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name="PPP"  Ascending="False"></FieldRef>
</OrderBy>
</Query>
```

This query is generating an error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>      at SPCAMLQueryHelper.SPWSLists.Lists.GetListItems(String listName, String viewName, XmlNode query, XmlNode viewFields, String rowLimit, XmlNode queryOptions, String webID)
>      at SPCAMLQueryHelper.WebServiceWork.ExecuteQuery.Worker()

Comment: How are you calling the code? With CSOM or SSOM?

Comment: Also, you shoud not have the `<Value>` part in an `<OrderBy>` statement

Comment: I am using CSOM to call this query. I am not deploying anything on Server. Actually I am testing this query using CAML Query Helper and the error mentioned above is shown in CAML Query Helper. I removed the <Value> part from the <OrderBy> statement. Results are same

Comment: You are also not passing any values in any of your `<Eq`> statements, and you should not wrap your `<IsNotNull>`:s in `<Eq>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in the query:

- You don't need `Value` in `OrderBy`
- You have `IsNotNull` inside `Eq`
- You have `Ascending` attribute in `FieldRef` for `IsNotNull`
- You have no values in `Eq` conditions. Consider using `IsNull` (unless you've just omitted values in the question).

Try this one:

```
<Query>
 <Where>
  <Or>
   <Or>
    <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
     <Value Type="Text"></Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name="Dream_x0020_Destination" />
     <Value Type="Text"></Value>
    </Eq>
   </Or>
   <IsNotNull>
    <FieldRef Name="PPP"/>
   </IsNotNull>
  </Or>
 </Where>
 <OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name="PPP" Ascending="False"/>
 </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback and great example of a working query.